# PuTTY Detaching turns into ^A

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I'm new to this and I'm hosting a garrys mod server with my VPS, and I have my VPS console connected to steam, but, I need to detach so I can return to "root@host". Currently, when I try to do CTRL+A+D, it just turns into "^A" as shown below:

**"Unknown command "" ^A Unknown command "" ^A^A^A "**

When I close PuTTY, the server closes also.  How do I avoid this and get back to my server session?

Comment: Detach from what? Are you running `screen` or `tmux`?

Comment: I'm not running any.. Perhaps i should do that haha.

Comment: Warrior mode on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `screen` command at the beginning of your session. Run `screen` and it'll give you a new session from which you can detach with <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>. Run your server application under this `screen` session.

The other part of the solution is to reattach later. `screen -ls` will list the sessions. And `screen -r` optionally followed by one of the `screen` session labels will reattach.

I would use the command either standalone as I logged in (literally `screen`), or in front on any command that starts your game server. In your example, where it begins `sudo ./srcds_run...` you would use `screen sudo ./srcds_run...`.

Comment: Ah.. My command is: **sudo ./srcds_run -game garrysmod +maxplayers 8 +map rp_venator_v3 +gamemode starwarsrp +host_workshop_collection 885520404 -authkey 9574BEE8540740F5F9B6A4C95BBAADDD**   So I need to add screen in front of ./srcds?                                                                            **EDIT**: It worked! Thank you so much.